# ViewHolder image setVisibility inside for loop

Tags: android

I have an RecyclerView adapter with the ViewHolder pattern. I have 5 ImageView in my layout that i need to control the visibility of depending on the response from the server. The response I get is a comma separated string(eg: 1, 4, 3). In this case i have to display the 1st, 4th and 3rd image.

The layout of the image view is:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_call_badge"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_exp"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/equity_badge"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/equity_icon"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/futures_badge"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/futures_icon"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/options_badge"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/options_icon"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/commodity_badge"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/commodity_icon"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/currency_badge"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/currency_icon"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I'm setting the visibility of the images as follows

```
//analystList[position].getAnalystCallTypes() gives the comma seperated string(eg. 1, 3)
String[] splitCallType = analystList[position].getAnalystCallTypes().trim().split(",\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i<splitCallType.length; i++) {
                setCallTypeBadge(holder, splitCallType[i]);
        }

private void setCallTypeBadge(ViewHolder holder, String position) {
    switch (position) {
        case "1":
            holder.equityBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "2":
            holder.futuresBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "3":
            holder.optionsBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "4":
            holder.commodityBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "5":
            holder.currencyBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
    /*if (position.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
        holder.equityBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (position.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
        holder.futuresBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (position.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
        holder.optionsBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (position.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
        holder.commodityBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (position.equalsIgnoreCase("5")){
        holder.currencyBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }*/
}
```

The problem is that it only sets the visibility of the 1st element in the response. ie if the string is 1, 2 , 3 it will set the visibility of 1 as visible but not 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you need to show them one by one or at the same time?

Comment: @Mike i need to show them at the same time

Comment: Then my answer is already written below by Suyash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your LinearLayout height and width set to 20dp? Shouldn't one of those be at least 100dp / match_parent depending on the layout direction?